# How do I setup virtualenv on a production Windows server using IIS and Helicon Zoo?

Tags: django, iis-7, virtualenv, helicontech

We are currently testing Django on a live server using Windows 2008 webserver and IIS7. To run Django projects on IIS we use Helicon Zoo (Python hosting package with Django).
The plan is to host multiple clients on that webserver and we would like to use virtualenv, so we can upgrade python packages for specific clients, without affecting the others.

The specific question is; when we have several virtualenvs on the server, how do we set up the different Django sites under IIS to use a specific virtualenv?

Thanks in advance for your time and answers,

Erik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not quite clear to me whether you need different versions of Python or different versions of modules, used in the application.

To have different python versions you can install another python manually, then go to applicationHost.config file, find . Engines declarations will be listed there. Create a copy of "python.2.7.wsgi" and edit the copy, name it like "python.2.5.wsgi" and change executable name path. This is how you can declare more engines with different versions and settings. Here you can find more information: [Helicon Zoo Module documentation](http://www.helicontech.com/zoo/module.htm)

As for Python modules, it is supposed that modules are installed locally in the client's web site in \python_modules\ directory. When you create new Django application using Helicon Zoo, it is configured to use isolated environment by default, you only need to learn how to use it right and tell your clients to follow guidelines. You can find the information in this article: [Running Django on Windows (with performance tests)](http://www.helicontech.com/articles/running-django-on-windows-with-performance-tests/)

Comment: Thanks, Yaroslav, this worked. We need different libraries per site. One extra remark though; this doesn't work out-of-the-box. It seems Django uses PIP to install the modules listed in requirements.txt. The ApplicationPoolIdentity used by IIS doesn't have rights to execute PIP by default. We had to give it rights on the C:\Python27 folder to fix this. To assign rights for the ApplicationPoolIdentity account, see http://serverfault.com/questions/81165/how-to-assign-permissions-to-applicationpoolidentity-account

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit further? There could be insufficient write permissions to the \python_modules\ folder under web site, i.e. c:\intepub\website\python_modules\ but we don't suppose install any modules under C:\Python27... Please check Django article again, there is a note not to install modules globally and deploy.py script example already contain appropriate command. It should work out of the box. If it doesn't, then we have to fix it.

Comment: Sorry, but we no longer have the log files from that situation. There were two errors in the deploy log about insufficient rights to run PIP. One was somewhere under the Python27 directory (but I can't tell you which folder specifically), the other error I could still find: "WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\config\\systemprofile\\AppData\\Roaming\\pip'". This second error seems to have no effect on running the site. Is PIP installed globally? Because if it is, I can imagine that the Anonymous Internet user doesn't have enough rights to run it.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Situation with insufficient NTFS permissions usually happen after installation of hosting control panel like Plesk or other product that override security settings. As for  'C:\\Windows\\system32\\config\\systemprofile\\AppData\\Roaming\\pip' folder I agree that client's script should not access this folder. We have updated deploy.py file example to run without access to this folder, note "update APPDATA env for pip" comment here: http://www.helicontech.com/zoo/usage/python-django.htm